# android-arm/libjnidispatch.so not found error

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jna

In my app, I am adding third party hardware connectivity and using their provided code for java. Also using `jna.jar` to interact with that code as it uses native library to load some `.so` files. It throws the error:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.) Please help where can I get the jar with android-arm/libjnidispatch.so in it.`
```

I tried adding android-arm.jar which is having libjnidispatch.so separately but compiler is looking for jna.jar's path. Thanks!

Comment: In my project, I have .aar file which has internal dependencies on .so files but for me i just added .aar dependency in my project.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663679/8034839 for how to add **libjnidispatch.so** properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Extract the com/sun/jna/linux-arm/libjnidispatch.so from the jar file
2. put the .so file in the following directory (when using android studio): yourproject\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libjnidispatch.so

And also please note that linux architecture != android architecture (google uses a different c library (bionic), which is a different one than the normal linux distributions)
For all architectures see:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native

Which version of JNA do you use? (There was a bug in JNA [4.2.2](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/662)/4.3.0 which might also be a cause)

Comment: I tried this but still giving the same error as its searching for the same path.

Comment: Thanks @Lozank, I was using jna4.2.3 now that issue resolved after using 4.5.0. I am using some other .so files which I kept on this path yourproject\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\ but it is showing error for the same. Can you please suggest me if I am wrong!